# Cambiar contenido de un <div> segun el mes

Tags: javascript

buen dia amigos, me gustaria cambiar el contenido del DIV zona horaria,segun el mes.

```
 <div clas="zonahoraria">
    <div class="zona1">
      <span>Perú</span>
      <img src="images/banderas/peru.png" alt="peru">
    </div>
    <div class="zona2">
      <span>Perú</span>
      <img src="images/banderas/eeuu.png" alt="usa">
    </div>
    <div class="zona3">
      <span>Perú</span>
      <img src="images/banderas/argentina.png" alt="argentina">
    </div>

</div>
```

por ejemplo si cambiamos de mes agregar argentina en zona 2 y viceversa.

no se por donde empezar, agradeceria su apoyo.
saludos

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cambie_div (){
hoy = new Date;
mes = (hoy.getMonth())+1;
if(mes==1)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_enero.gif" >')
}
if(mes==2)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_febrero.gif" >')
}
if(mes==3)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_marzo.gif" >')
}
if(mes==4)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_abril" >')
}
if(mes==5)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_mayo" >')
}
if(mes==6)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_junio.gif" >')
}
if(mes==7)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_julio.gif" >')
}
if(mes==8)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_agosto.gif" >')
}
if(mes==9)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_septiembre" >')
}
if(mes==10)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_octubre.gif" >')
}
if(mes==11)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_noviembre.gif" >')
}
if(mes==12)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_diciembre.gif" >')
}
document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = imagen_seleccionada;
}
cambie_imagen();
setInterval ("cambie_div()", 60000 ); 
// Esta linea hace que cada 60 segundo cheque si cambio de hora, y asi 
cambiar de imagen
```

amigos encontre eso, y trate de adecuarlo, ahora me encuentro en el dilema de como mostar codigo como este:

```
<div clas="zonahoraria">
<div class="zona1">
  <span>Perú</span>
  <img src="images/banderas/peru.png" alt="peru">
</div>
<div class="zona2">
  <span>Perú</span>
  <img src="images/banderas/eeuu.png" alt="usa">
</div>
<div class="zona3">
  <span>Perú</span>
  <img src="images/banderas/argentina.png" alt="argentina">
 </div>
 </div>
```

en un div dependiendo del mes..
ayuda por favor